# Why won't my objects die?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, phantom-reference

I'm trying to implement a mechanism that deletes cached files when the objects that hold them die, and decided to use `PhantomReference`s to get notified on garbage collection of an object. The problem is I keep experiencing weird behavior of the `ReferenceQueue`. When I change something in my code it suddenly doesn't fetch objects anymore. So I tried to make this example for testing, and ran into the same problem:

```
public class DeathNotificationObject {
    private static ReferenceQueue<DeathNotificationObject> 
            refQueue = new ReferenceQueue<DeathNotificationObject>();

    static {
        Thread deathThread = new Thread("Death notification") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        refQueue.remove();
                        System.out.println("I'm dying!");
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        deathThread.setDaemon(true);
        deathThread.start();
    }

    public DeathNotificationObject() {
        System.out.println("I'm born.");
        new PhantomReference<DeathNotificationObject>(this, refQueue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            new DeathNotificationObject();                  
        }
        try {
            System.gc();    
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
I'm born.
```

Needless to say, changing the `sleep` time, calling `gc` multiple times etc. didn't work.

**UPDATE**

As suggested, I called `Reference.enqueue()` of my reference, which solved the problem.

The weird thing, is that I have some code that works perfectly (just tested it), although it never calls `enqueue`. Is it possible that putting the `Reference` into a `Map` somehow magically enqueued the reference?

```
public class ElementCachedImage {
    private static Map<PhantomReference<ElementCachedImage>, File> 
            refMap = new HashMap<PhantomReference<ElementCachedImage>, File>();
    private static ReferenceQueue<ElementCachedImage> 
            refQue = new ReferenceQueue<ElementCachedImage>();

    static {
        Thread cleanUpThread = new Thread("Image Temporary Files cleanup") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Reference<? extends ElementCachedImage> phanRef = 
                                refQue.remove();
                        File f = refMap.remove(phanRef);
                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        c.setTimeInMillis(f.lastModified());
                        _log.debug("Deleting unused file: " + f + " created at " + c.getTime());
                        f.delete();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    _log.error(t);
                }
            }
        };
        cleanUpThread.setDaemon(true);
        cleanUpThread.start();
    }

    ImageWrapper img = null;

    private static Logger _log = Logger.getLogger(ElementCachedImage.class);

    public boolean copyToFile(File dest) {
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(img.getFile(), dest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            _log.error(e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ElementCachedImage(BufferedImage bi) {
        if (bi == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        img = new ImageWrapper(bi);
        PhantomReference<ElementCachedImage> pref = 
                new PhantomReference<ElementCachedImage>(this, refQue);
        refMap.put(pref, img.getFile());

        new Thread("Save image to file") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(ElementCachedImage.this) {
                    if (img != null) {
                        img.saveToFile();
                        img.getFile().deleteOnExit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Some filtered output:

2013-08-05 22:35:01,932 DEBUG   Save image to file: <>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7..0.PNG

2013-08-05 22:35:03,379 DEBUG   Deleting unused file: <>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7..0.PNG created at Mon Aug 05 22:35:02 IDT 2013

Comment: You don't actually enqueue anything.

Comment: So I should call `enqueue()`... got it, thanks!

Comment: See my answer, last line.

Comment: FWIW, you should not assume your finalization will *ever* get called.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx (relevant to Java too)

Comment: Of course, I only use it as a safety net. hence the `createTemporaryFile()` and the `deleteOnExit()` in my code... Anyway, thanks for a great read!

Comment: as i said in your other question, this example is not thread-safe (HashMap is not thread-safe).  you have at least solved the memory issue.  as i noted in my other comment, you don't need the extra map, just maintain the Reference in the ElementCachedImage.

Comment: Your probably right (I'll be more confident after testing it...)

Comment: If this is just a safety net, i would get rid of it. it just slows GC down. How about adding a method to your cache which removes the file on disc when the entry expires? no magic involved, can be invoked manually when required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is, that in your example the `PhantomReference` itself is unreachable and hence garbage collected **before** the referred  object itself is garbage collected. So at the time the object is GCed there is no more `Reference` and the GC does not know that it should enqueue something somewhere.

This of course is some kind of head-to-head race :-)

This also explains (without looking to deep into your new code) why putting the reference into some reachable collection makes the example work.

Just for reference (pun intended) here is a modified version of your first example which works (on my machine :-) I just added a set holding all references.

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class DeathNotificationObject {
    private static ReferenceQueue<DeathNotificationObject> refQueue = new ReferenceQueue<DeathNotificationObject>();
    private static Set<Reference<DeathNotificationObject>> refs = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        Thread deathThread = new Thread("Death notification") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Reference<? extends DeathNotificationObject> ref = refQueue.remove();
                        refs.remove(ref);
                        System.out.println("I'm dying!");
                    }
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        deathThread.setDaemon(true);
        deathThread.start();
    }

    public DeathNotificationObject() {
        System.out.println("I'm born.");
        PhantomReference<DeathNotificationObject> ref = new PhantomReference<DeathNotificationObject>(this, refQueue);
        refs.add(ref);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            new DeathNotificationObject();                  
        }
        try {
            System.gc();    
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Calling `enqueue` by hand is possible in your example but not in real code. it gives plain wrong result. Let me show by calling `enqueue` in the constructor and using another `main`:

```
public DeathNotificationObject() {
    System.out.println("I'm born.");
    PhantomReference<DeathNotificationObject> ref = new PhantomReference<DeathNotificationObject>(this, refQueue);
    ref.enqueue();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        DeathNotificationObject item = new DeathNotificationObject();

        System.out.println("working with item "+item);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("stopped working with item "+item);
        // simulate release item
        item = null;
    }

    try {
        System.gc();    
        Thread.sleep(3000); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output will be like this:

```
I'm born.
I'm dying!
working with item DeathNotificationObject@6908b095
stopped working with item DeathNotificationObject@6908b095
```

Which means that whatever you wanted to do with the reference queue would be done when the item is still alive.